# ui-grid - how set display name for select column when select-all disabled?

Tags: ui-grid

Much like my other question
"ui-grid - how set display name for select column when select-all enabled?"
but now I need to have select all disabled.  So changing "selectionSelectAllButtons" won't help.  I don't see what I could customize to get a column heading for the select columns.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague figured it out - CSS like this to make the column heading as "blurb":

```
div.left div.ui-grid-header-cell-row div.ui-grid-header-cell:after {
        content: "Blurb";
}
```

Although to set the column heading programmatically, you have to trigger off of the page being rendered which is hard to do.  That rendered event seems to be fired many times and it's important to perform the customization the last time (though doing it every time wouldn't hurt).